# Excel VB Get path from cell to Array

Tags: vba, excel

i've question. I create macro : the excels gets information and merges into one.
I'm trying to add more features.

how to get paths from cells in the workbook:

```
A1 path C:/drive

A2 path D/iop
```

etc. to the Array ?

My code:

```
Sub dzialaj()

    a = Array("path,path,path,path")
    Dim s
    Selection.ClearContents
    Dim orzeszek As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    For Each s In a
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(s)
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set orzeszek = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)


    Range("A3:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    orzeszek.Close


    Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read ranges from sheet into a 2d array.

If you only have a single column and want a 1d array you can use `Index` to grab the column of interest. The below declares `arr` as an unallocated dynamic array.
`inputRange` is then grabbed and use the `.Value` property a 2d array is generated. `Index` is used to slice out the first column generating a 1D array. As read in from the sheet, the array is 1 based, not 0.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim inputRange As Range, arr()
    Set inputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")

    If inputRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = inputRange.Value
    Else
        arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(inputRange.Value, 0, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Without using Index you would have a 2D array.

More info [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).